# jquery ajax trouble with returning a responce from my success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a react app, so i have a build in webpack. This is the part of my core related to the problem

```
import $ from 'jquery'

let ajax = (function () {
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
    let request = {
        get: (url, data) => {
            let settings = adjustSettings('GET', url, data);
            return $.ajax(settings)
        },
        put: (url, data) => {
            //TODO
        },
        post: (url, data) => {
            let settings = adjustSettings('POST', url, data);
            return $.ajax(settings);
        },
        delete: () => {
        }
    };

    function adjustSettings(method, url, data) {
        let settings = {
            method: method,
            url: baseUrl + url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data) || null,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: (response, textStatus, xhr) => {
                console.log(xhr);
                let obj = {
                    response: response,
                    xhr: xhr
                };
                return obj;
            },
            error: (error) => {
                return error;
            }
        };
        return settings;
    }

    return {request: request}
})();
export default ajax;
```

I the other file i am importing the ajax

```
import ajax from '../confing/ajax'
ajax.request.post("/user/register", data).then((obj) => {
    console.log(obj);
})
```

Now the ajax is beeing send to my backend and it works as intended, but when my `succes` function returns `obj` I dont seem to get any data inside my `.then((obj)` , by if try to `console.log(obj)`  inside the `success` function it works the data is there, so tl;dr; I seem to not be able to return the obj correctly from my `success`function. Any thoughts?